# How do multiple requests from same session always land on the same server?

Tags: http, session, server, httprequest, load-balancing

How do multiple requests from the same browser session always land on the same server? Does the server load balancer use session ID from multiple requests and redirect to same server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well that depends on the load balancer. Most of them support this kind of functionality (session stickiness).

For example [nginx](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/load_balancing.html) (on the free version) supports `ip_hash` which redirects all the requests from the same ip to the backend server, and nginx plus supports additionally balancing [based on session](https://www.nginx.com/products/session-persistence/) which is achieved with cookie.

[Haproxy](http://blog.haproxy.com/2012/03/29/load-balancing-affinity-persistence-sticky-sessions-what-you-need-to-know/) as well supports both the above methods to load balance, and is using cookie as well for the session stickiness.